# Unable to access Kubernetes Service on default TCP Port

Tags: kubernetes

I have a K8S service whose description is:

```
kubectl describe service/dynamic-destination
Name:              dynamic-destination
Namespace:         transparent-proxy
Labels:            xxx/component=http-proxy-service
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          xxx/component=http-proxy
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                100.68.154.85
IPs:               100.68.154.85
Port:              proxy  80/TCP
TargetPort:        2003/TCP
Endpoints:         100.96.17.39:2003
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

One the same namespace, I am opening up a curl pod and attempting to invoke the service as follows:

```
kubectl run curlpod --image=curlimages/curl -n transparent-proxy -i --tty -- sh
```

When I attempt to curl to the dynamic-destination service, here is what I see:

```
~ $ curl -vvv dynamic-destination "X-Destination-Name: google"
* Host dynamic-destination:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 100.68.154.85
*   Trying 100.68.154.85:80...
```

The service IP is correctly resolved, but I am unable to push traffic to the port 80. I even tried pushing to port 2003, but does not work.
Any thoughts on if I am missing something?

Grateful for your help.
Prabal

Comment: What Pod(s) are attached to the Service?  What program are they running?  Are they correctly listening on 0.0.0.0:2003?  The `kubectl describe` output does contain the critical detail that `Endpoints:` is non-empty – the Service's label selector match the Pod's labels – but otherwise the original YAML files are more useful than the derived `kubectl describe` output.